# Extracting specific values from a Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, extract

I want to use a Perl regex to extract certain values from file names.
They have the following (valid) names:

```
testImrrFoo_Bar001_off
testImrrFooBar_bar000_m030
testImrrFooBar_bar231_p030
```

From the above I would like to extract the first 3 digits (always guaranteed to be 3), and the last part of the string, after the last `_` (which is either `off`, or (`m` or`p`) followed by 3 digits). So the first thing I would be extracting are 3 digits, the second a string.

And I came out with the following method (I realise this might be not the most optimal/nicest one):

```
my $marker = '^testImrr[a-zA-z_]+\d{3}_(off|(m|p)\d{3})$';
if ($str =~ m/$marker/)
{
    print "1=$1 2=$2";
}
```

Where only `$1` has a valid result (namely the last bit of info I want), but `$2` turns out empty. Any ideas on how to get those 3 digits in the middle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there.

Just :
 - capture the three digits by adding parenthesis around: `(\d{3})`
 - don't capture `m|p` by adding `?:` after the parenthesis before it (`(?:m|p)`), or by using `[mp]` instead:

```
^testImrr[a-zA-z_]+(\d{3})_(off|[mp]\d{3})$
```

And you'll get :

```
1=001 2=off
1=000 2=m030
1=231 2=p030
```

Comment: Darn! So close. I swear, after X more years of practice I'll get these bloody regexes understood...!

Comment: @titus.andronicus, you can go on https://regex101.com/ to test your regexes, it also gives you what's inside your capturing groups, it is really useful to help debugging regexes ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can capture both at once, e.g with

```
if ($str =~ /(\d{3})_(off|(?:m|p)\d{3})$/ ) {
    print "1=$1, 2=$2".$/;
}
```

You example has two capture groups as well (`off|(m|p)\d{3}` and `m|p`). In case of you first filename, for the second capture group nothing is catched due to matching the other branch. For non-capturing groups use `(?:yourgroup)`.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need for regular expressions when a simple [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) will suffice:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split(/_/);
    my $digits = substr($fields[1], -3);

    print "1=$digits 2=$fields[2]\n";
}

__DATA__
testImrrFoo_Bar001_off
testImrrFooBar_bar000_m030
testImrrFooBar_bar231_p030
```

Output:

```
1=001 2=off
1=000 2=m030
1=231 2=p030
```